# using node, passport, & connect-flash.... why is my flash method undefined?

Tags: node.js, flash, express, passport.js

Good sirs.
While following a MEAN tutorial, I'm getting an `undefined is not a function` error when I try to `req.flash('error')` *(middle of the second code block)*

So... am I lacking a `require` in my controller, which would have given me the flash capabilities which are clearly set up in `express.js`?

I don't see `app` referenced anywhere in the controller, so I'm not sure how the controller is supposed to know what `flash` is. I understand how `exports` and `require` work to link files together, but that doesn't seem to apply here and there is no explanation in the tutorial.

**express.js**

```
 var flash = require('connect-flash');
    app.use(flash());
```

**users.server.controller.js**

```
var User = require('mongoose').model('User'),
    passport = require('passport');
...
exports.renderRegister = function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.user) {
        res.render('register', {
            title: 'Register Form',
            messages: req.flash('error')

        });
    }
    else {
        return res.redirect('/');
    }
};
...
```

**package.json** shows everything I need is installed

```
{
  "name": "myMEANapplication",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.12.4",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "ejs": "^2.3.1",
    "express": "^4.12.4",
    "express-session": "^1.11.2",
    "gulp": "latest",
    "mongoose": "^4.0.3",
    "passport": "^0.2.2",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

The repo for the completed tutorial project pages is [here](https://github.com/Hitman666/MEAN_MVC_3rdTutorial/blob/master/app/controllers/users.server.controller.js).

Answer (score -1):

did you place your

```
require('../app/routes/index.server.routes.js')(app);
require('../app/routes/users.server.routes.js')(app);
```

lines before or after you did

```
app.use(flash());
```

?

Comment: Before. And they should be AFTER. Thanks! Duh.

Comment: No worries. It's a common mistake.